# Error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed

Tags: psql

I'm kind of hitting my head against the wall trying to figure this out...

When I run `psql` in my terminal, it gives me:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I see the service running with `brew services`, but another one appears because I tried to upgrade PSQL as well, but that might've messed it up even more.

```
postgresql        started fella /Users/fella/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
postgresql@13     stopped
```

I've tried:

- `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast`
- output >> `pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid" does not exist Is server running?`
- `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`
- output >> `waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start server Examine the log output.`

I tried:

- brew update
- brew upgrade

which went without any errors, but I still get the same error when I run psql

I just ran

`➜  ~ code /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

`➜  ~ tail -n 100 /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`

And found a whole bunch of errors there. Lots of this happening:

> ```
> incompatible with server 2021-10-24 18:04:41.848 MDT [1038] DETAIL: 
> The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 13, which is
> not compatible with this version 14.0.
> ```

But this was the most recent one:

> 2021-10-24 18:09:45.680 MDT [4129] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.0
> on x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 13.0.0
>
> (clang-1300.0.29.3), 64-bit 2021-10-24 18:09:45.682 MDT [4129] LOG:
> listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432 2021-10-24 18:09:45.682 MDT
>
> [4129] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
>
> 2021-10-24 18:09:45.763 MDT [4129] LOG:  listening on Unix socket
>
> "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" 2021-10-24 18:09:45.814 MDT [4129] LOG:  could
> not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory 2021-10-24
>
> 18:09:45.815 MDT [4129] LOG:  could not open configuration file
>
> "/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf": No such file or directory
>
> 2021-10-24 18:09:45.816 MDT [4129] FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
>
> 2021-10-24 18:09:45.818 MDT [4129] LOG:  database system is shut down
>
> postgres: could not access the server configuration file
>
> "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
>
> postgres: could not access the server configuration file
>
> "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
>
> postgres: could not access the server configuration file
>
> "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or
> directory

Comment: Seems to be having trouble starting.  Example the log output?

Answer (score 0):

I worked with one of the instructors at my bootcamp to resolve this - we found that I had two instance of PSQL on my PC. We dug into the root folder and removed the older version 13 and re-ran the installation which solved all my issues.